# Jekyll + liquid: Get list of values from page metadata

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have some custom metadata in the pages of my Jekyll site like this:

```
---
title: Some title
topic: Quantum mechanics
---
```

I'd like to list all the pages by topic. So I thought about getting a list of all the topics, then iterate over that list. I know how to filter all the pages whose `topic` equals `Quantum mechanics`, but I don't know how to get a list of all the topics.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly list all topics with some clever liquid code, but you'll loose your time and add load on jekyll build.
It will be far more easy if you use jekyll builtin [categories](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#categories).